# automatically extract audio track and name file from video with avconv

Tags: bash, avconv

I'm writing a bash script to automatically extract audio track from a video file using `avconv`. This script should handle any video format and only extract the audio track without keeping the original codec conversion. For example:

```
extract_audio name.flv
```

where the audio track of the flv file is an mp3 should produce a file named `name.mp3`, but if it contains and aac track it should produce aumatically `name.aac`

For now my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dryname=${1%.*} #get remove video extention
avconv -i "$1" -vn -acodec copy "${dryname}.${audio_extension}"
```

The only part that I miss is how to get the codec used in the audio track of the video file. I'm sure it's possible to do it with an `avconv` command but I can't figure it out from the help page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
audio_extension=$(avconv -i "$1" 2>&1 | grep -io "audio:...."|cut -d ' ' -f2)
```

Comment: Maybe `avprobe` would be better than `avconv -i`.

Comment: Both "avconv -i" and "avprobe" give identical output about video and audio data. That way it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: Exactly, but 'avconv -i' does more operations, so if all you need is the output you should use the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I found a solution using grep only: `audio_extention=$(avprobe "$1" 2>&1 | grep -oP '(?<=Audio: ).*?(?=,)')`

Answer (score 1):

You can run below command firstly to check codec info, then do extract with proper suffix.

```
$ avconv -i test.mp4 2>&1 |grep Audio
    Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 62 kb/s (default)
```